# Call to `fgets` on stream generated by `popen` hangs

Tags: c++, macos, posix, popen, fgets

I have an application that uses the following piece of code to run a cmd and get its output:

```
std::string cmd = "ps -a -x -o pid,ppid,state,command | grep myProcess | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3 }'";
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
std::stringstream output;
std::string err;
int exitCode;
FILE* proc = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

if (proc == NULL) {
    exit(1);
}
while (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, proc) != NULL) {
    output << buf;
}
exitCode = pclose(proc);

std::string outputStr = output.str();
```

The problem I am having is that the function would get stuck on the `fgets` function randomly. I cannot consistently make it to get stuck.

How can that happen?

The code is running under macOS 10.10 and upwards.

Comment: The process won't close its own output until it exits. So reading to end of stream and then closing the process cannot work.

Comment: @EJP But when `ps` finishes, its `stdout` should get closed with an EOF which would trigger all the chain to finish processing their outputs with EOF. This in turn would make proc get an EOF which should make `fgets` exit with NULL.